# Change adapter based on viewpager position

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

I have a viewpager with 3 pages but a single fragment inside (with a recycle view). I want to change the content of the fragment based on the page Im in, so I dont need to create 3 fragments. Just one and adapt it. To do so, Im getting the current position on the viewpage and sending it to my fragment activity so I can change the adpater, but I always get errors with "...on a null object reference".

In my activity I have:

```
public class HintsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager ViewPagerHints;
    private hintFragment hintfragment = new hintFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hints);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ViewPagerHints = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerHints);
        if (ViewPagerHints != null) {
            setupViewPager(ViewPagerHints);
        }

        ViewPagerHints.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                hintfragment.changeAdapter(position);
            }
        });

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPagerHints);

        setTitle("Hints");
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager myViewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            adapter.addFragment(new hintFragment(), "Foods");
            adapter.addFragment(new hintFragment(), "Sports");
            adapter.addFragment(new hintFragment(), "Health");

        myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

And in my fragment activity (hintFragment):

```
public class hintFragmen textends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Adapter_Hints adapter_hints;
private HintsManager hintsManager= new HintsManager ();
private List<Hint> hintsListFoods ;
private List<Hint> hintsListHealth;
private List<Hint> hintsListSports;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hints, container, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));

    hintsListFoods = hintsManager.getFoodsHints();

    adapter_hints = new Adapter_Hints(hintsListFoods);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_hints);

    return recyclerView;
}

public void changeAdapter(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                hintsListFoods = hintsManager.getFoodsHints();
                adapter_hints= new Adapter_Hints(hintsListFoods);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_hints);
                break;
            case 1:
                hintsListSports= hintsManager.getSportHints();
                adapter_hints= new Adapter_Hints(hintsListSports);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_hints);
                break;
            case 2:
                hintsListHealth= hintsManager.getHealthHints();
                adapter_hints= new Adapter_Hints(hintsListHealth);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter_hints);
                break;
        }
    }
```

fragment_hints.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycleViewHints"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Logs:

```
12-21 10:19:38.468 30243-30243/com.support.android.iplfit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.support.android.iplfit, PID: 30243
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.support.android.iplfit.hintFragment.changeAdapter(hintFragment.java:57)
                                                                                at com.support.android.iplfit.Activities.hintFragment$1.onPageSelected(HintsActivity.java:46)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1939)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:679)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:663)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2255)
                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9943)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2663)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2344)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
                                                                                at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10163)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6184)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6313)
                                                                                at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                                at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-21 10:19:38.468 30243-30243/com.support.android.iplfit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: Please post your logs.

Comment: added to the post, Thank you.

Comment: And could you also post the code where you've initialized the RecyclerView

Comment: Also added to the post :)

Comment: can you post your fragment_hints.xml?

Comment: All It hasis the RecycleView. Post updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialised the object hintfragment in your Activity class which is not inflated to any parent view. And thus you are getting null pointer exception while you try to change the page of your ViewPager. Try the below code.

```
ViewPagerHints.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            ((hintFragment)((Adapter)ViewPagerHints.getAdapter()).getItem(position)).changeAdapter(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Error:(46, 60) error: cannot find symbol method getItem(int)"

Comment: Changed my answer. Just cast your Adapter. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hints, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));

    ...
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: ' 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference'